# Yii2: Use custom view for email

Tags: php, yii2

I am sending an email and so far I have this code:

```
\Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = "layouts/create-user";
$message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose ( 'layouts/create-user' , [ 'userData' => 'Hello' ] );
$message->setFrom ( [ 'sdfsdfsdfs234s@mail.com' => 'Admin DOC-Plus' ] );
$message->setTo ( 'don****km@inbox.ru' );
$message->setSubject ( 'Your account has been created' );
$message->send ();
```

Somehow, my variable `$userdata` is not available in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the layout and view file with the same one? why is that so they are for the view and layout files respectively and both these files cant be same.

If you are using `yii2-advanced-app` your mail `views` and `layouts` should go inside the **`common/mail/layouts`** and **`common/mail/views`** directory and if `yii2-basic` then it should go into **`app/mail/layouts`**. I will use the `basic-app` directory structure in the example below.

Add the following layout file **`html.php`** inside the `app/mail/layouts` if you don't have one and move your view inside the `app/mail/views` create the `views` folder if not exist.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Then you should look into the documentation for the **`compose()`** inside the [**`MailerInterface`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-mailerinterface.html) the `view` parameter is defined as

> The view to be used for rendering the message body. This can be:
>
> - a string, which represents the view name or path alias for rendering the HTML body of the email. In this case, the text body will be
>     generated by applying `strip_tags()` to the HTML body.
> - an array with `html` and/or `text` elements. The `html` element refers to the view name or path alias for rendering the HTML body,
>     while `text` element is for rendering the text body. For example,
>     `['html' => 'contact-html', 'text' => 'contact-text']`.
> - `null`, meaning the message instance will be returned without body content.

So change your code to the following I am assuming the view file named as `myView` change it accordingly

```
function sendMail() {

    \Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = "@app/mail/layouts/html";

    $message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose ( [ 'html' => '@app/mail/views/myView' ] ,['userData' => 'Hello'] // pass model to view);
    $message->setFrom ( [ 'sdfsdfsdfs234s@mail.com' => 'Admin DOC-Plus' ] );
    $message->setTo ( 'don****km@inbox.ru' );
    $message->setSubject ( 'Your account has been created' );
    $message->send ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If View file path like @app/mail/layouts/create-user  Then Please try this code**

```
$message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose ('create-user',[ 'userData' => 'Hello' ] );
$message->setFrom ( [ 'sdfsdfsdfs234s@mail.com' => 'Admin DOC-Plus' ] );
$message->setTo ( 'don****km@inbox.ru' );
$message->setSubject ( 'Your account has been created' );
$message->send ();
```

**In view file file print_r($userData); you will be get variable value **

Comment: I guess the first line of your code should be like this:
$message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose ('layouts/create-user',[ 'userData' => 'Hello' ] );
I have added the "layouts" in your path. Otherwise, error fired saying "The view file does not exist:"